# to_builder method returns empty hash from a Jbuilder view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

Lets say I have a user class

```
class User
  def to_builder
    json = Jbuilder.new
    json.user_id self.id
    json.firstname self.firstname
    json.lastname self.lastname
    json.email self.email
    json.profile_photo self.profile_photo
    json
  end
end
```

My controller renders a view which calls the to_builder method on a user object

```
user.to_builder.target!
```

However the JSON output which I receive is an empty hash {}

If I change the code in the view to not use the to_builder method but to directly use the jbuilder json, I get the desired output

```
json.user_id user.id
json.firstname user.firstname
json.lastname user.lastname
json.email user.email
json.profile_photo user.profile_photo
```

What am i doing wrong. I don't want to write code in my views but for some reason this stuff is just not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Simple Way

```
 class User
   def to_builder
    Jbuilder.new do |user|
     user.id id
     user.first_name first_name
     user.last_name  last_name
     user.email  email
     user.profile_photo profile_photo_path
    end
  end
 end
```

or

you can try

```
 def to_builder
  Jbuilder.new do |person|
   user.(self, :name, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :profile_photo)
  end
 end
```

and then

```
 user = User.new(1, "First Name", "Last Name", "myemail@gmail.com", "c:\users\my.png")
 user.to_builder.target!

 #=> {id: 1, first_name: "First Name", last_name: "Last Name", email: "myemail@gmail.com", profile_photo: "c:\users\my.png"}
```

Comment: have tried this. doesn't work. is user.to_builder.target! not allowed in views?

Comment: @DanMatlin I'm seeing the same thing where the view returns a string representation of a JSON object instead of an object. What was your solution?